# Firestore count read and writes of a single function in console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I watched many videos and read a lot in the docs but Im still quite unsure when to choose the correct approach for my situations. Like whn to to demolization on my data vs using a cloud function or how many reads does the `.exist()` dooes and so on.

Rather then asking all these cases I'm searching for a way where I can write a function `exampleFuntion()` which interacts with my firestore and in the code editor logs I can then see how many reads and writes it took to run the function once.

This is how I imagine it. :D With this I could simply learning by trying. Does anybody know how to do it in kind a like this way? I didnt find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the number of reads and writes of your app using the [Cloud Firestore Activity Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#firebase-console).
If you want to see the usage of an exact function, you can isolate it by running in a new Firebase project.

Alternatively, you could consider implementing a counter within your sample function that increases every time a read/write happens and log it at the final step of the function. Here is an example on that:

```
var reads = 0; 
var writes = 0;

function addData(data) { 
    db.collection("collectionName").set(data);
    writes++;
}
function getData() { 
    db.collection("collectionName").get().then((querySnapshot){
    reads = reads + querySnapshot.size;
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. the idea of the counter, could you add an example of a function with the counter? Im not sure which value I would count there.

Comment: @MarcelDz I've updated the answer adding an example of a function.

Comment: This will be slightly off, because queries charge a read even if no documents are included in the query snapshot.